# WPF Changing the size of my textbox when i cover it with my cursor

Tags: c#, wpf

In my program i have various textboxes which are too small for the text the user will want to write in, so i want to change the size of my Textbox when i hover my cursor over it. 
As soon as i leave the Textbox with my mouse it should go back to the normal size.

maybe with the MouseEnter Event.

`MouseEnter="Protokolbox1_MouseEnter"`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're better of looking at `GotFocus` event, that will cause the TextBox to expand when user Tabs in to the TextBox. And you need to show us that you made some effort to get that to work, we are here to help not to do the work for you.

Comment: Could you please provide a specific question? Does the code you gave not work for you for some reason? In addition: don't need to thank nothing to no one.

Comment: Why aren't the textboxes big enough initially? I also think your ui should work for a user who chooses to tab. Some users prefer to avoid using the mouse wherever possible how about them? What about touch screen users? What if they move the cursor out the way so they can see what they type? If they jiggle the mouse as they move their hand to the keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following example, you can change the width/height...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: There should be one more trigger for going back to old width when IsMouseOver is False.

Comment: Not really, when trigger value is not what it should be then it will revert to the old value of 100. The same happens if you change background on mouse over, it reverts once mouse leaves the object.